# Get the size of the documents in solr

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I have a set of solr documents, for example:

<long name="document_id">1</long>
<long name="size">1666</long>
<arr name="label">
 <str>A</str>
 <str>B</str>
 <str>C</str>
</arr>

<long name="document_id">2</long>
<long name="size">765</long>
<arr name="label">
 <str>A</str>
 <str>C</str>
</arr>

<long name="document_id">3</long>
<long name="size">456</long>
<arr name="label">
 <str>B</str>
</arr>

I have to query these documents and the output should be Label name and sum of size field across the documents. 
In this example:
A: 2431 (documet 1's size 1666+ documet 2's size 765)
B: 2122 (documet 1's size 1666+documet 3's size 456)
C: 2431 (documet 1's size 1666+ documet 2's size 765)

Is there any single query to find it? and also I have looked on stats in solr. But it is applicable for single valued fields.

Comment: This sort of post-processing is best done using a `Solr client library/language binding`. I could be wrong here, but I don't see how you could easily achieve this with Solr. I personally post-process Solr results using Python's `lxml library` --pretty easy to use. Is there a requirement that would inhibit using an external script?

Answer (score 0):

No you can not do that. A solr query will return a object from which you can parse required fields and display (do computations on) them. No query probably can do the addition operation you want.